# How to get the rotate key to affect clickable regions produced with hyperref's \hyperlink?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, rotating

I'm doing some experiments with `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` (from `hyperref`) used inside some TikZ nodes and I noticed an unexpected behaviour.

Please consider the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{test}{This is the target}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rotate=90] 
    at (0,0) 
    {\hyperlink{test}{This is the link?}};
  \node 
    at (4cm,0) 
    {\rotatebox{90}{\hyperlink{test}{This is the link}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

As you can see, when the `rotate` option is used to rotate a node and its contents, the hyperlink doesn't get affected; the text rotates but the clickable area remains unaffected. If the rotation is performed using a `\rotatebox` applied to the node contents, the hyperlink gets transformed appropriately.

I know that this behaviour has been noticed before and some alternatives (included the use of `\rotatebox`, `\adjustbox` or making the whole `tikzpicture` the contents of the hyperlink) have been suggested in the answers to [How to rotate hyperlink with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30266/3954), but I am not interested here in known workarounds; I want to know the reason behind the behaviour and whether or not it is possible to to get the hyperlinks to obey the `rotate` option for nodes.