# Hyperlinked image

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

There is some package that creates a hyperlink to an image created in latex, that is, to the image created to associate a link to a website.

Comment: Yes, hyperref is such a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\begin{document}
Oh, so many \href{https://www.marmots.org}{\tikz{\marmot}}s!
\end{document}
```

If you compile it, you'll see

[image]

and click on the cute fellow, you will be directed to a web site.

Let me stress that this is very basic. Much more profound applications can be found e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36111/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415756/121799).

Comment: is it possible that the same image has more than one URL?

Comment: @SamuelDiaz How would that work? Meaning where do you want to be directed if you click the button.

Comment: @marmat They are constructions in GeoGebra, it depends on the image so they are the URLs that you must have, por example: https://www.geogebra.org/m/kq43fhjz and https://www.geogebra.org/m/rtvengnj

Comment: The idea is that when you click on the image, a window appears offering which of the URLs you want to open one

Comment: @SamuelDiaz I am not aware of  (which is not to be confused with "I doubt that there is") a way to do that with LaTeX.